# Open source Change Data Capture tool for OSGI

Tags: database, osgi, apache-karaf, change-data-capture

I am looking for an open source osgi tool for database Change Capture on Apache Karaf. I was looking and I have found Debezium but it's not osgi ready any other suggestions ?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but perhaps you'd be interested in helping out with OSGi-fying Debezium?

Answer (score 2):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) works well in recent versions. I just did a [tutorial to show how to use it in OSGi](http://liquid-reality.de:8090/x/BQAbAQ).

Balázs Zsoldos helped me with it. He also has some more advanced tooling for it that allows to modularize your db schema see [everit cookbook Chapter persistence](http://cookbook.everit.org/persistence/index.html).

Comment: I am usinig Liquibase already with OSGI and it works fine but only to update database schema from my model classes. but does it help with change data capture ? I need something to watch databse events and inform in rela time an other bundle that there is something changed in the database since that bundle does not have a scope on the database. I don't think that Liquibase is made for that.

Comment: Ah .. I misunderstood. I thought you are talking about schema changes. For data changes you could take a look into camel sql and camel jpa. Though these are optimized for special transfer tables not for complex interrelated tables.